# How to set the working directory of maven 3.8 wrapper mvnw.cmd?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-wrapper

Scope: Windows

How to set the working directory of maven 3.8 wrapper mvnw.cmd?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is MAVEN_USER_HOME
e.g.
set MAVEN_USER_HOME=T:\temp

One needs to set the variable **before** working with **mvnw.cmd**

If you are doing mvnw.cmd --version without setting the variable first, it will create plenty of files in %USERPROFILE%.

- mvn = maven
- mvnw = maven wrapper

Source: https://maven.apache.org/wrapper

It took me a while to find that peace of information.